# Is there an official statement of when MathML will be available on the iPhone/iPad?

Tags: iphone, ipad, mathml

Everything I have found online shows rumours that WebKit development of MathML support is coming soon. Does anyone know where I might find an official statement of this work, and when (from an official source) this will happen?
Thank you.

Comment: You might try the iOS development documenation of WebKit: [http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/safari/index.action](http://developer.apple.com/devcenter/safari/index.action)

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I am an unofficial volunteer, but I've been working on the WebKit MathML implementation for the last couple of months. I just tested MathML in the released version of Safari on an iPad 2 and it's turned on. I assume this is also true on the iPhone, but not yet in Google Chrome or presumably the Android browser. There are still a lot of layout bugs even in basic MathML in WebKit, but I and perhaps others are working on them. I don't think you'll find any official statement anywhere from Apple or Google or WebKit (if you do, please let me know!). WebKit seems to be a classic democratic (anarchic?) open source project, albeit one that is supported by some of the world's largest companies, and that benefits or will benefit literally billion(s) of people.  It's pretty cool to be contributing to it, I must say.  For more info, you might check out:

- [Webkit and MathML](https://vismor.com/documents/site_implementation/viewing_mathematics/S5.SS1.php)
- [Google Chrome and MathML](http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=6606)
- [jqMath - MathML On](http://mathscribe.com/author/jqmath.html?mathml=on): for experimenting with MathML in Safari (full disclosure, I also wrote jqMath)
- [Reporting WebKit Bugs](http://www.webkit.org/quality/reporting.html): you can also do an advanced search to show current bug reports in the MathML component

If anyone wants to contribute e.g. by reporting some new MathML layout bugs, it'll help focus our (my) work and increase the speed with which MathML patches get reviewed and checked in to WebKit.  As I say, it feels great to have a chance to help so many people - I recommend it.

Comment: I tested the epub 3+mathml version of this book http://lightandmatter.com/calc/ on someone else's ipad 2 a couple of days ago. I only observed one general problem, but it's a big one. Stretchy operators are not rendered properly; they're rendered with little ladder symbols.

Comment: Thanks. I found this one too via one of your links, that also shows current status of the project. https://trac.webkit.org/wiki/MathML

Comment: Great comments, thanks! The wiki link summarizes what's been implemented, though as I say there are still some bugs. Also I've passed on the missing font (I think) on iPad 2 comment to another coder, and I'll look at it myself also after finishing my current patches.

Comment: Well - it seems there's some [official word](http://blog.chromium.org/2012/11/a-web-developers-guide-to-latest-chrome.html) from Google Chrome at last :)